# check whether shared memory is attached or not

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork, shared-memory, spawn

I am implementing with shared memory. 
In order to access the same shared memory, whenever the `shared memory address assigned pid` and the current `pid` are different, the address is reassigned through system V's `shmat`. 
When the `child process` terminates or the `parent process` deletes the shared memory, it `shmdt` the last `shmat` address and `shmctl` the `shared memory id`.

I think this is correct behavior for `spawn`, but is this also correct behavior for `fork`?
If I use `fork`, I expect the same memory access without `shmat` even though the `pid` is different.

If it was a process created with `fork`, when it had the id and address of the shared memory, I thought that the `child process` should either run `shmdt` on the existing address or update the `pid`.

1. Is there a way to check if the id and address of the shared memory that the process has are valid?
2. Does `shmdt` in a forked child process not affect the parent process? (Does the parent process still access to shared memory well?)
3. Is it necessary to `shmdt` all shared memory owned by the `parent process` in the `child process` created by `fork` in order for normal `shmctl` to proceed?